# C# overloading operators of A operator&(B l,B r)

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I am working on lazy object composer

```
class Bitset
{ 
   private   List<bool> _data;   
   public Bitset(List<bool> vector)
   {
      _data = vector;
   }
   public virtual bool  GetElement (int i)
   {
      return _data[i];
   }


   public Bitset(){}

}
class BitsetComposer:Bitset
{        
   readonly private Bitset _a,_b;
   private Func<bool,bool,bool> _composer;
   public BitsetComposer(Bitset a,Bitset b, Func<bool,bool,bool> composer)
   {
      this._a=a;
      this._b=b;
      this._composer=composer;
   }

   public override bool GetElement (int i)
   {
      return _composer(_a.GetElement(i),_b.GetElement(i));
   }

   public static BitsetComposer operator & (BitsetComposer a, BitsetComposer b)
   {
      return new BitsetComposer(a,b,BitsetComposer.And);
   }

   public static bool And(bool a,bool b){return a&b;}

}
```

This is not fine, because, it would be desired that & can also take base class

```
//replaced with
//public static BitsetComposer operator & (BitsetComposer a, BitsetComposer b)
public static BitsetComposer operator & (Bitset a, Bitset b)
{
   return new BitsetComposer(a,b,BitsetComposer.And);
}
```

But I got error:

> Error CS0563: One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both operands are expected to be of base class type, you only need to move the `operator` code to the base class.

From [7.2.2 Operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> User-defined operator declarations always require at least one of the
>   parameters to be of the class or struct type that contains the
>   operator declaration. Thus, it is not possible for a user-defined operator to have the 
>   same signature as a predefined operator.

```
class Bitset
{ 
   private   List<bool> _data;   
   public Bitset(List<bool> vector)
   {
      _data = vector;
   }
   public virtual bool  GetElement (int i)
   {
      return _data[i];
   }

   public Bitset(){}


   public static BitsetComposer operator &(Bitset a, Bitset b)
   {
       return new BitsetComposer(a, b, BitsetComposer.And);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you need to make sure one of your parameters is of the `BitSetComposer` class.

The reason you cannot do `(BitSet a, BitSet b)` is because then there would be no reference to your custom class. Consider this example:

```
var a = new BitSet();
var b = new BitSet();
var result = a&b;
```

In this example there is no reason to expect the `BitsetComposer`'s operator to be used, right? So the compiler complains when you try to overload the `&` operator without using a at least one of the corresponding type.

So you'll need to make three total methods:

```
public static BitsetComposer operator & (BitsetComposer a, BitsetComposer b)
{
   return new BitsetComposer(a,b,BitsetComposer.And);
}
public static BitsetComposer operator & (BitSet a, BitsetComposer b)
{
   return new BitsetComposer(a,b,BitsetComposer.And);
}
public static BitsetComposer operator & (BitsetComposer a, BitSet b)
{
   return new BitsetComposer(a,b,BitsetComposer.And);
}
```

Comment: I also want to use just example you mentioned. I dont see any reason against that.